# getPromotionsList() in Demandware

Tags: promotions, demandware

I want to use `dw.campain.Promotion` object in *demandware* to print a list of 
active / inactive promotions.

Did you have a method to recover the full list of promotions in *demandware*?

Answer (score 3):

```
var PromotionMgr = require('dw/campaign/PromotionMgr');
var promotions = PromotionMgr.getPromotions();
```

It will return a collection with all active / inactive promotions.